# Is it possible for a Python mixin to access a global variable?

Tags: python, django, mixins

I have a mixin that defines `finalize_response()` method intended to override in another class:

```
class APILoggingMixin(object):
    """
    Provides logging functionality by overriding finalize_response(). 
    Intended to be mixed in with any rest_framework.views.APIView
    """
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info('Some message.')
        return super(APILoggingMixin, self).finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

And a class which implements the `finalize_response()` method. In the same module, the `logger` global var is defined:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CategoryDetail(APILoggingMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a Category.
    """
    model = Category
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

How can I access the `logger` variable in the mixin?

Comment: are they in the same file? if so just do `logger.whatever` from inside one of the methods ...  if not then do `from otherfile import logger` then just use it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizing that `APILoggingMixin.finalize_response` takes `self` which is a `CategoryDetail` instance, we could attach logger to CategoryDetail

```
class CategoryDetail(...):
    logger = logger

class APILoggingMixin(object):
    def finalize_response(self, ...):
        self.logger.info('Some message.')

# Or through get_logger()
class CategoryDetail(...):
    def get_logger(self):
        return logger

class APILoggingMixin(object):
    def finalize_response(self, ...):
        self.get_logger().info('Some message.')

    def get_logger(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

# Or take advantage of the fact that `self.__module__` equals to `__name__` in the module of `CategoryDetail`
class APILoggingMixin(object):
    def finalize_response(self, ...):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.__module__)
        logger.info('Some message.')
```

Comment: Independently, I actually did the first one. Thanks!